# How to hide android keyboard's input field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, keyboard

Hi I am currently developing a game for android on unity. (2d game)

I've been looking for answers everywhere since a week but still no answer ... So I decided to ask here.

Actually my problem might be very simple but I am new to Android development and I had no idea of how it was walking.

**1** - I want the input field right at the top of the keyboard to be hidden, to put a custom input field made with unity UI system.

**2** - Adjust keyboard's position (Only for like 50px from the bottom of the screen) so that i can put my stuffs in there.

I get that keyboard appears automatically when an InputField is focused or selected. But it dosen't make disappear the input field from the native keyboard.

From what I learned serching , I get wether I need to make plugin for unity or export my unity project to eclipse to do so.
But unfortunetly I have no base on java or xml.
I should really learn at least basic skills on these stuffs but for now I can't afford to spend time to learn from base.

What would be the most easy way ?

Hope someone can help me out.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change the **input field** to just **text**,

And when you click on the text, show your own keyboard ui.

This is an alternative solution I think.

Comment: That seemed most absurd solution to me at the first time.
After like a week of serching. I realized that was the fastest and easy way to get the job done.
In the time You wrote it I had already made it and it actually didnt even take that much time and works pretty well.
I also think that this way is the easiest ... If there are ppl like me without any base of xml !

Comment: You still can choose it as an answer. ^_^